# Modify UDP packet payload with XDP, extending beyond received size

Tags: c, networking, xdp-bpf

I'm wanting to use XDP_TX to re-transmit a packet received, whilst also modifying the packets content. I have swapped the dst and src ip address around so it successfully gets sent back to the sender, that's all working perfect.

I however would like to modify the packets payload to something else, the problem I am hitting and can't wrap my head around is I'm only able to modify the contents up to the size of the received packet and not add more data on (e.g only send back 26 bytes of payload if they sent 26 bytes too).

I'm able to grab the payload of the UDP packet by going along the normal IP headers until I get to the data:

```
uint8_t *udp_bytes = data + sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct udphdr);
```

Along with this, doing bounds checking to ensure the packet is the length which I expect:

```
if (!(udp_bytes + 25 > (uint8_t *)data_end)) {
```

This type of packet will always be 26 bytes in total. I'm then able to modify the packets contents (albeit in a bad way) by the following:

```
*udp_bytes++ = 0xff;
*udp_bytes++ = 0xff;
*udp_bytes++ = 0xff;
*udp_bytes++ = 0xff;
*udp_bytes++ = 0x80;
*udp_bytes++ = 0x17;
*udp_bytes++ = 0xe2;
*udp_bytes++ = 0x98;
*udp_bytes++ = 0xa0;
*udp_bytes++ = 0x20;
*udp_bytes++ = 0x97;
*udp_bytes++ = 0x20;
*udp_bytes++ = 0x60;
*udp_bytes++ = 0x6c;
*udp_bytes++ = 0x69;
*udp_bytes++ = 0x60;
*udp_bytes++ = 0x79;
*udp_bytes++ = 0x52;
*udp_bytes++ = 0x6f;
*udp_bytes++ = 0x6c;
*udp_bytes++ = 0x65;
*udp_bytes++ = 0x70;
*udp_bytes++ = 0x6c;
*udp_bytes++ = 0x61;
*udp_bytes++ = 0x70;
```

I'm however limited to the amount of bytes that the incoming packet was. If I try and add another byte on, the verifier will prevent it loading. Is it possible to extend the packet to allow more payload? I've seen `bpf_xdp_adjust_head` but unsure if this is what I need!

Comment: So allocate a bigger buffer? Unclear what the problem is.

Comment: `bpf_xdp_adjust_head()` is just what you want indeed. It will add some extra space at the beginning of your packet, so you could e.g. add an encapsulation layer. Example workflow: allocate more space with it, move (copy) Ethernet header to the beginning of new space, insert encapsulation header between new Ethernet and old IP header. I think latest kernels also have a matching `_adjust_tail()` helper if you need to grow (or shrink, by the way) the end of the packet instead.

Comment: I'll give _adjust_tail a go, since I'm modifying the payload that is at the end of a packet, thanks

Comment: @Qeole _adjust_tail only appears to shrink the packet, unless this has been updated in a newer kernel version?

Comment: It has, but this is [very recent](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/bpf/bpf-next.git/commit/?id=c8741e2bfe872425ea6f10bb6f7dc1d67bc60c3a) indeed. You'd need current bpf-next tree (it should be available in Linux 5.8).